# Sort Generic List to show using foreach (mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, sorting

I've a List<> included in ViewData.

```
reloadCollectionModel.ReloadCollection = new List<ReloadModels>();
foreach (DatoPaquete dato in result) 
{
reloadModel = new ReloadModels();  
reloadModel.IdPaquete = dato.id;     
reloadModel.Value = dato.monto;      
reloadCollectionModel.ReloadCollection.Add(reloadModel); 
}

//disordered (it's works)
ViewData["ReloadModelsCollection"] = reloadCollectionModel.ReloadCollection.AsEnumerable();
```

Then in razor I show this List using foreach. This works.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["ReloadModelsCollection3"] as List<ReloadModels>)
{
   <a href="@Url.Action("Confirm", "Reload", new { item.Value, item.IdPaquete, item.DaysToExpired })"></a>
}
```

My problem... When I sort the list, I can't use foreach to show them (launch Exception).

```
ViewData["ReloadModelsCollection3"] = reloadCollectionModel.ReloadCollection.OrderBy(item => item.Value).AsEnumerable();
```

I need to change my ViewData? Or change my foreach?

Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you post the actual exception?

Comment: share exception message please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are casting to a List.  After ordering make them a list as follows:

```
ViewData["ReloadModelsCollection3"] =
    reloadCollectionModel.ReloadCollection.OrderBy(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

That is not AsEnumerable